# Python - draw functions on a array

Tags: python-3.x, draw

I use python 3.6
I need a library for drawing functions like:

```
DrawLine(..), DrawCircle(..), DrawText(..)
```

But I don't want to put the output to a file or screen.
I simply need to put the color/pixel data to an array.

The array is only 60x40 pixel big.
I use the array to send it out to device via USB.
It needs to be fast because I calculate it 60 times per second.
I tried PIL library but it slow and show the picture also on screen.

What will be the best solution for me?

Comment: Asking for a library is considered off topic on SO.

Comment: Pillow is the image python libary. And it does not require to show image on screen. the should be a buffer wich you can send into anywhere.